# Unzipping a .gz file without removing the gzipped file

Tags: command-line, files, gzip, gunzip

I have a file `file.gz`, when I try to unzip this file by using `gunzip file.gz`, it unzipped the file but only contains extracted and removes the `file.gz` file.

How can I unzip by keeping both unzipped file and zipped file?

Answer (score 367, accepted):

Here are several alternatives:

- Give `gunzip` the `--keep` option (version 1.6 or later)

  > `-k`   `--keep`
  >           Keep (don't delete) input files during compression or decompression.

  ```
  gunzip -k file.gz
  ```
- Pass the file to `gunzip` as stdin

  ```
  gunzip < file.gz > file
  ```
- Use `zcat` (or, on older systems, `gzcat`)

  ```
  zcat file.gz > file
  ```

Comment: Where do I get a version of `gunzip` with `-k` or `--keep`? I'm using version 1.5 in Gentoo and it has no such option.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda It was added in version 1.6. I've amended my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With the other option this is now the best answer.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda If you need `--keep` but don't have it, just make a copy of `file.gz` first.

Comment: @Liam That's an ugly hack given that you need to copy it to a third unique file name and then move. And the answer already has a *much* better solution.

Comment: `gunzip -c file.gz > file` or `zcat file.gz > file` also work. https://superuser.com/questions/45650/how-do-you-gunzip-a-file-and-keep-the-gz-file/45651

Comment: What if there are more files in the .gz?

Comment: @Pyjong gunzip or zcat of a file containing multiple compressed streams will  produce the concatenation of all the streams. `cat thing1.gz thing2.gz > both.gz; gunzip -k both.gz` will produce a single file named `both` and won't delete `both.gz`. The gzip man page recommends that, if you need to compress multiple flles while preserving all their names, you use something like `tar` to bundle them up and give tar the `z` option to gzip the entire bundle.

Comment: gunzip doesn't have a -k option. Is this answer still valid?

`# gunzip -k my.gz
gzip: invalid option -- 'k'
Try 'gzip --help' for more information.`

Comment: @Worp What is the output of `gunzip --version` ? The -k option is only in version 1.6 and beyond.

Comment: fml, that makes sense. `$ gunzip --version
gunzip (gzip) 1.5` My bad, I will edit my comment! **edit:** I can't edit my comment anymore, so let's leave this up for clarification. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 45):

Without requiring a temporary file:

```
 zcat somefile.gz > somefile
```

Comment: This also works great if you want to pipe the output to another command with buffering without deleting the file `zcat file.sql.gz | mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M db`